# How to access the picture in picturebox, which is located in tab tabcontrol?

Tags: c#, winforms

Creating a programm which can take photo from camera and insert it in new tab, then user can save a picture from picturebox.

```
TabPage newTabPage = new TabPage();
newTabPage.Text = $"{g}";
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTabPage);
PictureBox newpicturebox = new PictureBox();
tabControl1.TabPages[g].Controls.Add(newpicturebox);
```

So, names of picboxes are not unique.

I tried to get access like that

```
tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex]
                    .Controls.newpicturebox.Image
                    .Save(fs,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I expect that it is possible to get a photo in PictureBox in a unique tab.

Comment: `names of picboxes are not unique.`  Give it a unique name: `...Controls["uniqueName"]...`  Cast appropriately.

Comment: `tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().First().Image.Save(...)`, assuming there's one PictureBox per Tab and it's a direct child of the TabPage. Otherwise, in any case, you need to know which PictureBox was selected